# SELECT SUM android no return decimals

Tags: android-layout, select, sqliteopenhelper

I have this query that calculates the sum, but it gives me decimal numbers, how can I get the decimal?

`Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(
"SELECT ROUND(SUM(ore),2) AS totore FROM "+DbHelper.TURNI_TABLE+" WHERE MESE = 'Gennaio'",null);`

Comment: It gives you, or it does not give you?

Comment: then how can I get decimal numbers, can you help

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a decimal data type with a fixed number of digits.

`ROUND` returns a plain floating-point number, i.e., `ROUND(42)` will return `42.0`; it is your program's responsibility to format this number as you want.

If the only reason you're using `ROUND` is that you want to format the number, you should not do this in the database but only in your program.